How to prerender dynamic routes in angular 17?
Not able to prerender routes that is not defined in angular.json file
Implemented angular universal in angular 17 where routes are statically defined as:

"prerender": {
"builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
"options": {
"routes": [
"/",
"/test",
"/test/4"
]
},
in angular.json file.

As per the angular documentation I need to define routes that need to be prerender for dynamic routes. But I have a list of data which on navigating can generate uncountable routes such as (/test/5, /test/6, /test/89.... etc.) So to define uncountable routes it is not feasible. So how to tackle such problem ?

The whole use case of pre rendering, is to have content available for the web crawlers of Google search or any search engine to index the files and make your content searchable to users, the content just need to have the textual values not the full angular interactivity.
E.G. A website with a blog can prerender the blog so that, the blog details can be made visible to the web crawlers, this improves seo score. The website will get ranked higher in Google search
Since using the numbers specified in prerender routes, we can generate the pages during ng build,
This use case generally is for blog posts or other cases with a definite length, infinite is not something that falls under this use case
As per the angular docs, you can create a script that creates the routes programmatically and then specify the routes.txt file in the angular.json and it will work fine
Angular docs for prerendering

Talking about the script that creates the routes programmatically, i have created that one too which on build creates all routes available in the list and generates prerendered file for those routes. But problem arises , when i add new list (suppose creates route /test/911) the new routes does not get prerendered until and unless i need to rebuild it again. Also, let us suppose i have a existing list of ids (1,2,3) that creates routes (/test/1, /test/2, /test/3) and they are prerendered. If i delete id of 1 then the prerendered routes of id 1 is still available.

So , i just need solution if it is possible to tackle in angular. I have a
scenario to update the meta tags based on the id (1,2,3.....)  which i navigate dynamically.

@saajan-pixel you need to use the script to connect to the database get the list of ids, get the list of current routes and then create the routes.txt instead of randomly generating them. routes will get generated only when you run a build, else prerendering will not happen, that is by design!
